# How can I get branch name in aws codebuild for bitbucket?

Tags: continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using bitbucket as a code repository and Aws codebuild/pipeline for CI/CD.

What is the value of CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION env. variable in aws codebuild for bitbucket?

Answer (score 3):

To get the branch name in the build step, use the Environment variables feature.

Add an Environment variable (Key: BRANCH, Value: #{SourceVariables.BranchName}) in the Build step, and then this variable can be called inside the build script like $BRANCH

[See this for more details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html#actions-variables-examples-env-branchname)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

My pipeline has a source part in which it copy from bitbucket and store in s3.

I have a source artifact as a s3 bucket. so it will return s3 ARN.

Source version `arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-<region>-<accountnumber>/<path>`